# Scroll down event 5 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So what I'm trying to make is changing a fixed background image 4 times ( one scrolldown - one image change) and after the fourth image is up, the div with the images becomes "relative" so I can scroll down to the rest of the content on the website (as well when I scroll up, the images become fixed again and change in a reversed consecutivity).
I decided to use this code, but I'm not sure how to make it work for my 5 scrolls

```
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (st > lastScrollTop){
          $("#backroundimage").addClass("backgroundimage1");  //down scroll code
      } else {
          $("#backroundimage").removeClass("backgroundimage1");  //up scroll code
      }
      lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```

A good example of the functionbility I'm trying to achieve is http://airnauts.com/, after all the scrolling to the top area is done, the website scrolls down to the rest of the content and vice-versa when scrolling up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the question again I think I understood what you wanna do (I can't open the link you gave).

The thing is that if you want just have a top section that changes its background on scroll you cloud write something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numberofscroll = 0;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $("#out").scroll(function(){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--;
        if (numberofscroll<6){
            change_background(numberofscroll);
        }
    });
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Here a working example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/frqL0y6s/

If you want this 'top section' disapear after the last scroll, you cloud do:

```
$("#out").scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--;
    if (numberofscroll<6){
        change_background(numberofscroll);
    }
    else{
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: that's almost what I wanted, but when I scroll back to top, the image doesn't appear back. Here is the website I'm struggling with http://prntscr.com/975xta . The top truck image is the one I want to be changing on scroll down, 4 different truck angles, and after that I scroll further to the rest of the content in the website (and when I go back to top, the images should be back there). Sorry I'm not able to get it by myself, but I'm pretty new to javascript, so I have some troubles with getting the logic right. Thanks in advance, Denis.

Comment: @DeneaNovac I forgot to update lastScrollTop value so 'numberofscroll' works properly. 
I updated the answer with a new jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you ended my pain :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
var numberofscroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
       numberofscroll++;
       if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()){ // you reach to window bottom
          if(numberofscroll == 1){
               // first time scroll
          }else if(numberofscroll == 2){
             // second time scroll
          }else ... so on till you reach to 5

       }else{

       }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I do add to the "else" part? I mean how do I count the scrolls when I go up on the page? If I scrolled a total of 50 times ( I mean it's a variable, I can scroll even 200 times), how to make the div with the images come to fixed ?

Comment: @Denea Novac (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--

Comment: @jolmos please mention him in your comment  type @ and his name

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work because your var lastScrollTop can't egal to st because she is undefined. And more this first variable is useless. Just defined one variable in the loop and make your different test :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  st = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
    st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st > 200){
      test one;
    }else if(st > 400){
      test two
    }else{
      default
    }
  })
})
```